# OpenLayers 6.5.0 not parsing GML 3.2 with multiple featuretypes

Tags: openlayers, gml, mapserver, web-feature-service

I can't get openlayers `6.5.0` to parse a WFS 2.0.0 response in GML 3.2, when the response contains **multiple featuretypes**. It' works as long the response contains only one featuretype.

I've put together a simple example with fake responses, as they come from our MapServer (7.2.2|7.6.2).

- Git: https://github.com/msch-alpgis/js-e5njpe
- Working example: https://js-e5njpe.stackblitz.io

I think it's because MapServer has nested FeatureCollections in the response (same for GeoServer 2.17.0). If only one featuretype is returned, then the response has one level less and `ol.format.WFS` is able to read the features.

Am I missing something? Any advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head over to the github issue for a temporary solution and future informations:
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/12389